# Want to check if youtube url(video) is exist and date published/modified using vb.net

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net, youtube

I have requirement where I have excel sheet contains youtube URLs. I want to fetch this URLs and validate with youtube. I want below information.
 - Whether URL/video is exist.
 - Date created/updated.
 - Whether URL/video was exist but deleted now. If so, deleted date.

I want to achieve this in windows application using vb.net without using youtube API.

Also, I want to read/update excel in vb.net without using OleDBDataProvider and Microsoft.Office.Interop.

Can somebody please help me out on this.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

First, to check the if the video is existing, you can use the [Videos: list](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/videos/list) to return a videos that match the API request. By doing this, you can now verify if the videoId of the video is existing or not.

Here is the [sample request](https://developers.google.com/apis-explorer/#p/youtube/v3/youtube.videos.list?part=id&id=kmXXXLBL3Nk&_h=1&), just pass `id` as your part parameter and the `videoId` in the id parameter.

```
{
 "kind": "youtube#videoListResponse",
 "etag": "\"uQc-MPTsstrHkQcRXL3IWLmeNsM/ZHvOwtluy6sCNoIMjJVPsNKhBTc\"",
 "pageInfo": {
  "totalResults": 1,
  "resultsPerPage": 1
 },
 "items": [
  {


   "kind": "youtube#video",
   "etag": "\"uQc-MPTsstrHkQcRXL3IWLmeNsM/m-PtiixITeo8icgmD0t6X8DGyMA\"",
   "id": "kmXXXLBL3Nk"
  }
 ]
}
```

Now, if the videoId is invalid or not existing your response should look like this:

```
{
 "kind": "youtube#videoListResponse",
 "etag": "\"uQc-MPTsstrHkQcRXL3IWLmeNsM/ZCAnB4VKeQ7X3vzSCnmpxyOQqUk\"",
 "pageInfo": {
  "totalResults": 0,
  "resultsPerPage": 0
 },
 "items": [
 ]
}
```

For the date published, you can use the part `snippet` like [this](https://developers.google.com/apis-explorer/#p/youtube/v3/youtube.videos.list?part=snippet&id=kmXXXLBL3Nk&_h=4&) to get the date in the `publishedAt`

```
"kind": "youtube#video",
   "etag": "\"uQc-MPTsstrHkQcRXL3IWLmeNsM/uVmd9wiVAjnCz_wJuE9qrbXsJRU\"",
   "id": "kmXXXLBL3Nk",
   "snippet": {
    "publishedAt": "2016-10-20T08:08:19.000Z",
    "channelId": "UCTEAryTk0JGFSLNZ0tBIw2w",
    "title": "Kobe's  Last 3 minutes and 20 seconds    Lakers   Jazz 4 13 2016",
    "description": "#IDOL",
```

Comment: Thanks KENdi for your answer. However, I don't want to use youtube API. I want to achieve this without youtube API in vb.net

Comment: Also, how to manipulate excel without using OleDBDataProvider or Microsoft.Office.Interop. Is there any other way to read/update excel in vb.net?